Keyboard doesn't work after suspend in Ubuntu 22.04
This is a very similar issue to: Keyboard doesn't work after suspend in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  I wanted to comment there, but I don't have enough reputation points.
I have a Dell Inspiron 5570 laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.4.  Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic.  I have been running Ubuntu on this machine since ~2018 without ever doing a fresh install, only upgrades, and have never had issues.  Within the last month, the keyboard doesn't work after waking from suspend.  Most of the time, the keyboard is completely unresponsive.  A few times, the enter key has been "stuck", even though the key is not stuck mechanically.
During boot, the keyboard seems to be enumerated here:
[    0.398107] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4

After suspend, I don't see any kernel messages related to the keyboard, although I see many errors relating to r8169/pcieport (which are also new).  There has not been a BIOS update for ~1 year, so I don't believe it is firmware related.
Any advice would be appreciated!  I am going to try and install some older kernels and see what happens, but thought I would reach out to the community as well.
